# django unable to run mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I try run my django project on apache2 (Ubuntu). My error.log is:

```
[Sun Jun 08 11:50:29.635281 2014] [:error] [pid 2582] [client 127.0.0.1:46627]     for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
[Sun Jun 08 11:50:29.635299 2014] [:error] [pid 2582] [client 127.0.0.1:46627]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 350, in url_patterns
[Sun Jun 08 11:50:29.635353 2014] [:error] [pid 2582] [client 127.0.0.1:46627]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The included urlconf %s doesn't have any patterns in it" % self.urlconf_name)
[Sun Jun 08 11:50:29.635384 2014] [:error] [pid 2582] [client 127.0.0.1:46627] ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf kitty.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
```

and my wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
path = '/home/s/py/django/kitty'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "kitty.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**UPDATE**

My urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('frontsite.urls', namespace='frontsite')),
)
```

Comment: …begging the question, what's in `urls.py`?

Comment: Is your `ROOT_URLCONF` well defined?

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'kitty.urls'

Comment: I sometimes faced the same error, it happens when I forget to include my Classes inside `__init__.py` of any packages or have an invalid class reference in there. Have you  checked that all your `__init__.py` contains valid entries? Using that class reference classes causes urls.py to fail

Comment: I don't get it, my ./manage.py runserver works, i have to do something in \_\_init__.py?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove any stale urls.pyc file which may have been compiled when using the builtin development server. If you copied the code across to a separate Apache installation, including the .pyc files and date time stamps changed on files, Apache could use the stale .pyc file if it has a newer time stamp than the corresponding .py file.

Also ensure that if you are making changes to Python code files while the application is running on Apache that you are causing a restart of Apache else your new code changes will not be reloaded.